# Find the value of $\lim_ {n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f( x + \frac{1}{n^2})dx$

Tags: real-analysis

> Define  a sequence  of   function  $(f_n)$   as follows   $f_n(x) = f( x+ \frac{1}{n^2})$ where  $f: \mathbb{R}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $is a  continious  function . Find the  value   of $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f( x + \frac{1}{n^2})dx$

My attempt : $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f( x + \frac{1}{n^2})dx=  x^2 /2 + 0 ] _{x=0}^{x=1}= \frac{1}{2}$

Is its true ?

Comment: No, it's not, for instance if $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: @PhoemueX  how $f$ is identically equal to $0 ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a direct approach:
$$ \int _0^1 f(x + \frac{1}{n^2}) dx = \underbrace{\int _\frac{1}{n^2}^{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}} f(u) du}_{u-sub,\ u=x + \frac{1}{n^2}} = F\bigl(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\bigr) - F\bigl(\frac{1}{n^2}\bigr)$$

Now we take the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \Bigl ( F\bigl(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\bigr) - F\bigl(\frac{1}{n^2}\bigr) \Bigr) = \underbrace{F\bigl(\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2})\bigr) - F\bigl(\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{1}{n^2})\bigr)}_{because \ f \ is \ continues} = F(1) - F(0) = \int_0^1 f(x)dx$$
So a you can see, if you can show the sequence converges uniformly, you can just change the order of limit and integral, and get the same result.

Comment: thanks u @Uros kosmac

Comment: You are welcome